Using Jest to mock an AWS S3 call results in Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
I'm having an issue with a test that tries to mock a an S3 call with Jest.
The module under test does something like this
import { S3Client, CopyObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const s3 = new S3Client();

const copyObjectCommand = new CopyObjectCommand({
      Bucket: bucket,
      CopySource: source,
      Key: key,
});

await s3.send(copyObjectCommand);

Where I want to mock the s3 client using a Jest test that looks like this :
import { S3Client, CopyObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { handler } from "../src/index";

jest.mock('@aws-sdk/client-s3')

const mockedS3Client = new S3Client() as jest.Mocked<S3Client>;

describe('handler', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    it('should successfully copy object and return file report', async () => {

        // The 2 mock calls below are failing due to Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

        // mockedS3Client.send.mockResolvedValueOnce({}); // Mock successful response
        // mockedS3Client.send.mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error("S3 copy failed")); // Mock error response


        const event = {id: '67890'};

        const result = await handler(event);

        expect(result).toEqual({
            id: '67890'            
        });

        // These work just fine.
        expect(mockedS3Client.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(mockedS3Client.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(CopyObjectCommand));

    });

});

I'm unable to get these mockResolvedValueOnce / mockRejectedValueOnce calls to work due to the Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' error

The return type of send is generic (you're using this overload) and is usually inferred from the argument you're providing (in this case a CopyObjectCommand). But fundamentally mocking what you don't own is a bad idea - if you put a facade around the S3Client you'd have something much simpler to replace with a test double and could describe the actions in your own domain's language.
